# Is there a software with which I can freeze the state of my computer?

Tags: operating-systems

Is there a software with which I can freeze the state of my computer? For example, virus can't delete anything, even I can't delete files, just add them!

So every time the computer starts it loads the same programs, same versions, and my new files are stored separately.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_(software)

Comment: A: "Yes, there is software like that".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Deep Freeze. It's the standard. Almost every university, internet cafe shop, public library... uses it

http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/standard/

Basically, when you restart your machine, everything will be reset back to the state when you freeze it. Even if you format your HDD. Even if virus screw your machine up. One restart and eveything's back.